# Implementing jQuery currency converter with facetWP slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, facetwp

I've added currency conversion to a site I'm working using [Curry](http://curry.netyou.co.il/demo),  - which works great for almost all of what I'm trying to do. However the only area that it doesn't work on is the labels for the facetWP  price slider ([example](https://facetwp.com/demo/cars/?fwp_base_msrp=16800.00%2C492425.00)). It converts the figure initially, but when a user interacts with the slider, the number in the labels underneath reverts to the original currency.

My initial thinking was to have the conversion trigger whenever the label value changes - but I can't think of a way to do this.

The only change I've made vs the example is to separate the slider labels into different classes (rather than sitting in the same span tag) so I could target them independently as below.

```html
<span class="facetwp-slider-label price">$1,090</span>
<span class="facetwp-slider-end-label price">$6,400</span>
```

Comment: How about recalculating the price each time the slider is reset?